# mysql rbar situation

Tags: mysql

What would be the best way to handle this situation?

I'm working on off the shelf software, and it is storing user defined field names in the database as a row instead of adding a new column to the table. It looks like this:

```
   ID fieldName  fieldValue propertyId
    1 latitude   23.192     id_property1
    2 longitude -10.323     id_property1
    3 latitude   23.192     id_property2
    4 longitude -11.824     id_property2
    5 latitude   25.254     id_property3
    "                                   "
```

I need to filter this table based on user input for fieldName and fieldValue, so if the user enters fieldName="latitude" AND fieldValue="23.192" it would return id_property1 and id_property2. But if the user enters fieldName="latitude" AND fieldValue="23.192" AND fieldName="longitude " AND fieldValue="-10.323" it would just return id_property1.

I made an approach using for loops in php, but I'm concerned that it would bog down under a lot of records.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a self-join:

```
SELECT p0.propertyId
FROM propsTable AS p0
JOIN propsTable AS p1 ON p1.propertyId=p0.propertyId
WHERE p0.fieldName='latitude' AND p0.fieldValue=23.192
AND p1.fieldName='longitude' AND p1.fieldValue=-10.323
```

Comment: Wouldn't that return no records, as there is no record that contains both fieldName='latitude' AND fieldName='longitude'?

Comment: nm that worked. Do I need to add another join for each condition I need? Let's say I have three conditions. 

SELECT p0.propertyId 
FROM propsTable AS p0 
JOIN propsTable AS p1 ON p1.propertyId=p0.propertyId.
propsTable AS p2 ON p2.propertyId=p0.propertyId
WHERE p0.fieldName='latitude' AND p0.fieldValue=23.192 
AND p1.fieldName='longitude' AND p1.fieldValue=-10.323 
AND p2.fieldName='sq_feet' AND p2.fieldValue>2000

Comment: Yes, though there's a `JOIN` keyword missing in that (just before `propsTable AS p2`).